# Descriptive statistics for full dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which has only numeric values and I would like to calculate the descriptive statistics of the **full** data frame.

```
            REQ1     FAC2   SUCCESS     AVE_MARK  
    1        8        3        9           5
    2        4        3        6           6
    3        6        5        4           3
```

I don't want to calculate the descriptive statistics for each column which can be done fore example with the `psych` package, `describe(df)` or with `summary(df)`.

Comment: It appears a matrix would be a better data structure for this data.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unlist` the dataset and apply `summary`

```
summary(unlist(df1))
```